# Can we write apps for Ubuntu with Vala and Glade Interface Designer?

Tags: html, ubuntu, qml, glade, vala

How can we create apps for Ubuntu in Vala? I had a look on the Ubuntu website and all I can see so far is QML and HTML5 and Javascript (and *some* mention of C++ :-).

Now while these options are great for me, I would still prefer to write *this* project in Vala for now before jumping into something completely new again.

I come from Windows. I tried Elementary OS but had to stop using it due to its instability (when booting), and so far Ubuntu has been perfect. I used to write apps in Vala and GTK (with Glade). Can we write apps that way for Ubuntu? (I realise that Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu).

I wouldn't normally ask a question like this on here but I have not found a single result online suggesting that we can write Vala apps in and for Ubuntu and from what I can see right now, there is no mention of Vala on the Ubuntu website either.

Comment: As Vala is basically a C preprocessor, there is no reason it would not work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. GTK+ applications can be run on any Linux distribution that has the libraries installed. In fact, much of Ubuntu's Unity desktop is written in Vala.

Comment: Really? That's awesome. I'm so glad the big guys are using Vala. It's a wonderful language. as I said before, I come from Windows and most of my experience is with C++ and C#. Knowing that I can now use Vala (which is very similar to C#) is just awesome. Thanks @apmasell.